# PostgreSQL 9.0 64 bit Contrib Installation in Windows

Tags: postgresql

I've done some installs of PostgreSQL 9.0 64 bit on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

When I connect to these instances, PGAdmin complains of the following:

> The server lacks instrumentation Functions.

Apparently one is supposed to use the "official" pgInstaller program to install contrib modules in Windows PostgreSQL installs, including the server instrumentation.

However, the pgInstaller is only being maintained up to the PG9.0 RC, not the latest 9.0.1 version.

Given that, how do I get non-default contrib modules installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, where did you get the idea that it's only maintained up until 9.0 RC? It's most definitely available for 9.0.1. Go to http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows, and you'll find it.

That said, installation of contrib modules is covered in the documentation at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/contrib.html. If you're building with  mingw, that should just work. If you're building with msvc, then skip the build steps - they are always built on msvc - and just do the install/load step.

Comment: On the link you've provided, it states "pgInstaller is a Windows Installer package that offers advanced configuration options. pgInstaller packages are only being maintained for PostgreSQL 8.2 and 8.3.". So it's not even supported up to 9.0RC.

Comment: Hi Magnus, as far as I can tell this is where I'd expect to find the pgInstaller for 9.0.1 for Windows. http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/binary/v9.0.1/  Can you please point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Go to the download page, as suggested. Click the link for "Download the one click installer". Follow the instructions. pgInstaller was replaced with the on-click-installers in 8.4. AFAIK they include all the contrib modules and then some.

Comment: Thanks Magnus. My problem was that in most documentation for adding contrib modules in windows installs, the pgInstaller is mentioned as the way to get it done. It's not clear that the contribs are all included in the one-click installer, and that they're easily installed by running the scripts in the share folder.

Comment: a postscript: my reason for asking this question was that when I opened the server status app, it would say that log files weren't available. The way to fix this problem is to run PostgreSQL\9.0\share\contrib\adminpack.sql on the postgres database.